# Convert csv to json using phython

Tags: json

This is my code and it convert successfully. However, when i import this json into firebase and it state that Invalid JSON files.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('C:/Users/Senior/seaborn-data/Denver DatasetCleaning Finalize.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('C:/Users/Senior/seaborn-data/Denver DatasetCleaning Finalize.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("OFFENSE_CODE ","OFFENSE_CATEGORY_ID","FIRST_OCCURRENCE_DATE","DATE","YEAR","MONTH","DAY","TIME","HOUR","MINUTE","INCIDENT_ADDRESS","GEO_LON","GEO_LAT","NEIGHBORHOOD_ID")


reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: (minor) recommend marking your code as code in the editor

Answer (score 1):

each time `json.dump` is called it is outputting json. but several json strings concatenated together are not still json

what you maybe want to do is read the entire csv into a variable, then `json.dump` that